# mouse_event почему не ловит клик? if (state & 0x0004) C++

Tags: c++, mouse-event

Пишу кликер который должен ловить события мышки и обрабатывая их, выводить результат в консоль.

При указании абсолютного значения (0x8000) - работает только первое по списку, при конкретизации (0x0002, 0x0008) - нет.

Как исправить? Где копать и на что грешить?

```
if (state & 0x0002)
{
    std::cout << "LBM" << endl;
    mouse_event(0x0002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Sleep(50);
}
else if (state & 0x0008)
{
    std::cout << "RBM" << endl;
    mouse_event(0x0008, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Sleep(50);
}
```

Comment: А какое на самом деле значение `state` перед этими if-ами?

Comment: auto state = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON);

Comment: В следующий раз в подобных вопросах всегда пишите какая OS (вы может и удивитесь, но далеко не все пользуют винду) и каким билиотечным вызовом вы получаете инфу.

Comment: Благодарю за совет, обязательно учту в следующий раз. Спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Протупил, мой косяк.

Это и есть корень проблемы.

**auto state = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON);**

> вызов GetAsyncKeyState (VK_LBUTTON) всегда возвращает состояние левосторонней физической кнопки мыши, независимо от того, преобразована она в левостороннюю или правостороннюю логическую кнопку мыши.

Детальнее искать тут: http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Keyb_input/fn_getasynckeystate.htm

Также ошибка была в auto state
Об этом тут: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/auto-cpp?view=msvc-170